# Why isn't my 320px media query being applied?

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

I have the following two media queries:

```
@media  (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 359px){
    .hero-unit h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 0.2em;
        line-height: 0.5em;
        letter-spacing: -5px;
        color: inherit;
    }
    .hero-unit p {
        font-size: 0.2em;
        font-weight: 10;
        line-height: 0.5em;
        color: inherit;
    }   
    .hero-unit {
        background: url("../img/now320.jpg");
        height: 5em;
        width: 15em;      
        padding: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }   
    h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 20;
        line-height: 0.5em;
        color: inherit;
    }   
}

@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    .hero-unit h1 {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 0.2em;
        line-height: 1em;
        letter-spacing: -5px;
        color: inherit;
    }
    .hero-unit p {
        font-size: 0.2em;
        font-weight: 50;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: inherit;
    }   
    .hero-unit {
        background: url("../img/now360b.jpg");
        padding: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
        height: 10em;
        width: 18em;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }   
    h2 {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 20;
        line-height: 1em;
        color: inherit;
    }   
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why the 320 width rule is not being applied at all to my HTML page, even though I've resized it using the responsive design tool in Firefox to have a width of 320px.

I checked the CSS styles using Firebug to see what's going on. I only see the `@media (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 479px)` part being applied. That is, its not a case where the CSS rule I think should be applied is being overwritten. What's happening is the rule is never applied at all. Why?

Comment: Can you post the full page code / link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes browsers just simply don't allow for a viewport to be smaller than a certain size, and I think that line is down around 360, so it may simply not be registering, even with the tool you mention. I can't say, because I'd need to see the live example.

Have you checked the site on an actual mobile device, or at least an emulator? The [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/) is pretty easy to use.

As an aside, if you want to work **mobile first** - there is the idea of writing your CSS for 320 devices first, with **no media query**, as the 'baseline' experience. That is where you specify font families, colors, generally applied styles. *Then* you add in media queries to work on larger and larger sizes, and that is where you specify changes in layout and text size. The point being - don't wrap your 320-359 styles in a media query as it will be the basic experience for everyone.

Comment: How accurate is this Opera Mobile Emulator?  I've downloaded and am trying it.  Some of the device sizes are way off.  like the Asus EEE series....

Comment: I'm not sure in which way you're measuring accuracy - but, I don't really know. (To be honest, I mostly use the iOS emulator in XCode, it's just a pain to dig up.) If you're referring to the size of the screen, keep in mind that your desktop monitor is a lot less pixel dense than these devices. Here is a good run down of how to use the emulator: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/30/responsive-designs-opera-mobile-emulator/  One neat thing to note is that it can be hooked up with Opera's dragonfly debugger (aka Firebug for Opera)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish the 320px rule to be applied for all the page you need to write it like this

```
@media  (min-width: 320px)
```

without any and (min-width....) after it